# Safe maximum amount of nodes in the DOM?

Tags: html, dom, cross-browser, out-of-memory

For a web application, given the available memory in a target mobile device<sup>1</sup> running a target mobile browser<sup>2</sup>, how can one estimate the maximum number of DOM nodes, including text nodes, that can be generated via HTML or DHTML?

How can one calculate the estimate before

- Failure
- Crash
- Significant degradation in response

Also, is there a hard limit on any browser not to cross per tab open?

**Regarding Prior Closure**

This is not like the other questions in the comments below.  It is also asking a very specific question seeking a method for estimation.  There is nothing duplicated, broad, or opinion based about it, especially now that it is rewritten for clarity without changing its author's expressed interests.

---

**Footnotes**

[1] For instance, Android or IOS mobile devices sold from 2013 - 2018 with some specific RAM capacity

[2] Firefox, Chrome, IE 11, Edge, Opera, Safari

Comment: As always, try it! It is almost impossible to tell because it depends on how the page is laid out, what kind of css you have, transitions, javascript, etc. That said, I tend to find that at about 5,000 - 10,000 DOM elements desktop browsers start feeling quite sluggish.

Comment: Approaching size limits on a device that does not contain a hard disk with physical platters will not likely cause slow-downs as on a desktop or workstation where swapping causes a notable degradation in response times.

Comment: Just linking here some similar questions: [Javascript performance problems with too many dom nodes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365741/javascript-performance-problems-with-too-many-dom-nodes), [How many HTML elements can “modern” browsers “handle” at once?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21611822/how-many-html-elements-can-modern-browsers-handle-at-once), [html DOM node limits](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33135738/html-dom-node-limits)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a question for which only a statistical answer could be accurate and comprehensive.

**Why**

The appropriate equation is this, where N is the number of nodes, bytes<sub>N</sub> is the total bytes required to represent them in the DOM, and the node index `n ∈ [0, N)`.

> bytes<sub>N</sub> = ∑<sup>N</sup> (bytesContent<sub>n</sub> + bytesOverhead<sub>n</sub>)

The value requested in the question is the maximum value of N in the worst case handheld device, operating system, browser, and operating conditions.  Solving for N for each permutation is not trivial.  The equation above reveals three dependencies, each of which could drastically alter the answer.

1. The average size of a node is dependent on the average number of bytes used in each to hold the content, such as UTF-8 text, attribute names and values, or cached information.
2. The average overhead of a DOM object is dependent on the HTTP user agent that manages the DOM representation of each document.  W3C's [Document Object Model FAQ](https://www.w3.org/DOM/faq.html) states, "While all DOM implementations should be interoperable, they may vary considerably in code size, **memory demand**, and performance of individual operations."
3. The memory available to use for DOM representations is dependent upon the browser used by default (which can vary depending on what browser handheld device vendors or users prefer), user override of the default browser, the operating system version, the memory capacity of the handheld device, common background tasks, and other memory consumption.

**Rigorous Solution**

One could run tests to determine (1) and (2) for each of the common http user agents used on handheld devices. The distribution of user agents for any given site can be obtained by configuring the logging mechanism of the web server to place the HTTP_USER_AGENT if it isn't there by default and then stripping all but that field in the log and counting the instances of each value.

The number of bytes per character would need to be tested for both attributes values and UTF-8 inner text (or whatever the encoding) to get a clear pair of factors for calculating (1).

The memory available would need to be tested too under a variety of common conditions, which would be a major research project by itself.

The particular value of N chosen would have to be ZERO to handle the actual worst case, so one would chose a certain percentage of typical cases of content, node structures, and run time conditions.  For instance, one may take a sample of cases using some form of randomized *in situ* (within normal environmental conditions) study and find N that satisfies 95% of those cases.

Perhaps a set of cases could be tested in the above ways and the results placed in a table. Such would represent a direct answer to your question.

I'm guessing it would take an excellent mobile software engineer with a good math background and a statistics expert working together full time with a substantial budget for about four weeks to get reasonable results.

**A More Practical Estimation**

One could guess the worst case scenario.  With a few full days of research and a few proof-of-concept apps, this proposal could be refined.  Absent of the time to do that, here's a good first guess.

Consider a cell phone that permits 1 Gbyte for DOM because normal operating conditions use 3 Gbytes out of the 4 GBytes for the above mentioned purposes.  One might assume the average consumption of memory for a node to be as follows, to get a ballpark figure.

- 2 bytes per character for 40 characters of inner text per node
- 2 bytes per character for 4 attribute values of 10 characters each
- 1 byte per character for 4 attribute names of 4 characters each
- 160 bytes for the C/C++ node overhead

In this case N<sub>worst_case</sub>, the worst case max nodes,

```
= 1,024 X 1,024 X 1,024
  / (2 X 40  +  2 X 4 X 10  +  1 X 4 X 4  +  160)

= 3,195,660 . 190,476.
```

I would not, however, build a document in a browser with three million DOM nodes if it could be at all avoided.  Consider employing the more common practice below.

**Common Practice**

The best solution is to stay far below what N might be and simply reduce the total number of nodes to the degree possible using standard HTTP design techniques.

- Reduce the size and complexity of that which is displayed on any given page, which also improves visual and conceptual clarity.
- Request minimal amounts of data from the server, deferring content that is not yet visible using windowing techniques or balancing response time with memory consumption in well-planned ways.
- Use asynchronous calls to assist with the above minimalism.

Comment: I suggest adding paging or windowing through data sets to the list of HTTP design techniques, which fits in with the third bullet item. I would also increase the node overhead to over 100 bytes because there are pointers to the data, the hashmap of attributes, overhead of collection headers and links, the pointer to the jump tables of each inheritance parent, and event listener pointers and structures.

Answer (score 2):

There is no limit for the DOM. Instead there is a limit for a running application, called 'browser'. As all other applications, it has a limit of 4GB of virtual memory. How much of resident memory is used depends on the amount of physical memory. With low RAM you might get to situation of constantly swapping in and out (having affordable amount of swap memory). Some systems (Linux, Android) have a special kernel task to kill applications if the system runs out of memory. Also, the maximum size of application in Linux like systems is usually limited to 2MB of virual memory and can be changed by `ulimit` command.

Comment: How much memory does 1 non-text  DOM node tkae on average ?

Comment: It depends on browser, I think.

Comment: On a side note, no browsers are 32 bits anymore. Not even on mobile platforms. (Not saying that you can use 4GB+ on an Android device anyway though)

Comment: @Krumelur: For Linux and Android the limit of 4GB is set in the kernel virtual memory manager, and not related to the bit-ness of system bus and/or processor. It just means that 4GB are dedicated to *each* running process in Linux - not overall.

Comment: @Thevs Are you referring to ulimit -v or something else?

Comment: @Krumelur: ulimit -v sets the maximum amount of virtual memory for *users*, not for root. For root it is unlimited by default (i.e. limited to 4GB). In any case linux kernel reserves 4GB logical memory page for any process.

Comment: I am pretty sure you can allocate more than 4GB virtual memory. But maybe I misunderstood you

Comment: The system allocates 4GB for each running process. Isn't this more than enough for modern systems? Fresh installation of Linux has about 100 running processes. Android - about 50.