# Comparing different DOM nodes which ones are more performant?

Tags: html, dom, pseudo-element, textnode, dom-node

Trying to reduce the amount of DOM nodes I did some research on this, but have not found any comparing numbers, like is it better to use two DOM elements instead of two pseudo-elements or is it better to use 20-characters text-nodes instead of 10-characters DOM-elements (assuming it contains much more extra parameters than a text-node (aren't they cached or something?))?

The target is to simplify work with big DOM tree (mostly a table with some structure in each cell with about a 30000 DOM-elements total).

I've read W3 specs on pseudo-elements, but did not found any useful info.

So is there any common rules or is it may be discovered only with benchmarks?

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42590269/safe-maximum-amount-of-nodes-in-the-dom) as well, but it did not help a lot, as my question is about comparing different nodes - which should be preferred to improve performance?

And yes, I know about the `cell-reusing` approach, but it also depends on the complexity of cells (in IE11 scrolling lagging a lot, much more than just render entire structure at once).